# ¿Cómo optimizar esta función en R?

Tags: r, funciones, bucle-for, programación-funcional, bucles

Supongamos que tengo un vector de esta forma:

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,)
```

y quiero cambiarlo a este resultado:

```
x
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 3
```

Es decir, que a partir del primer 1 se agregue +1 al valor siguiente. 
Hice la siguiente función y opera correctamente:

```
zero_to_n <- function(x) {
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
        if(x[i]==0) {
        x[i]=0
        }else if (x[i]==1){
        x[i]= i +1 - which(x==1)[1]     
        }
    }
x
}

x<- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
zero_to_n(x)
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 3
```

Mi pregunta es simplemente si esta función se puede optimizar dado que utiliza `for`. Honestamente me sigue costando mucho trabajo pensar con la familia `apply` para este tipo de cosas. Agradezco cualquier comentario y sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si conceptualmente lo que buscas es numerar los valores `1` del vector, puedes resolverlo sencillamente de esta manera:

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
x[x == 1] <- seq(1:length(x[x == 1]))

[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3
```

Básicamente generamos una secuencia de enteros de 1 a la cantidad de `1` que tenga el vector y asignamos dicha secuencia en las posiciones que correspondan. Sin embargo esta forma funciona distinto a como lo haría tu función en caso que el vector tuviera otro patrón:

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)
x[x == 1] <- seq(1:length(x[x == 1]))
x

[1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 4 5
```

En este caso tu función trabaja distinto, el retorno sería: `[1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 5 6` por lo que si esto lo que esperas, deberíamos hacer algo así:

```
first_x <- which(x==1)[1]-1
ifelse(x==1,seq(x)-first_x,x)
```

Comenzamos a numerar los `1` pero con la posición relativa al vector.

Comment: Gracias, Patricio. Te comento que el vector siempre tendría la misma estructura: inicia con ceros y, en determinada posición, sólo unos. Básicamente es para crear variables para análisis de series de tiempo interrumpidas donde se asigna 0 a todas las observaciones previas a una política pública y 1, 2, ...,n, las observaciones que empiezan a correr a partir de la aplicación de la política. Te agradezco mucho tu respuesta.